# Elementery Hera auto mount nfs don't work

Tags: release-hera, mount, shared-libraries

I try to auto mount NFS shares over my local network. I add to /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.0.24:/mnt/Toshiba/dietpi_userdata /mnt/nas nfs defaults 0 0
```

I see service on start:

```
mnt-nfs.mount
```

but Elementary don't mount that shares after reboot.I have to do it manually:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.24:/mnt/Toshiba/dietpi_userdata/ /mnt/nas
```

I disabled my firewall. I have the same config in second laptop with Ubuntu 19.10 and it works fine.
Regards Przemek

Comment: You can try https://www.linuxtechi.com/automount-nfs-share-in-linux-using-autofs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you type sudo mount -a
and then sudo mount after you changed in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Hi @Sysadmin, I add /etc/fstab etry and then I make: `sudo mount /mnt/nas/` and `sudo mount 192.168.0.24:/mnt/Toshiba/dietpi_userdata` then reboot. I make the same steps in second laptop with Ubuntu and it works.

Comment: can You tell me where I have to add -a ??

Comment: All you have to do is to make changes in /etc/fstab. You do not have to mount it manually 
sudo mount -a in terminal is adding everything from /etc/fstab automatically. Mount command should show those resources as mounted. Check this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303846/where-are-nfs-v4-logs-under-systemd

Comment: Hi, I mount with sudo mount -a but this still don't work after reboot. Do I have to add sudo mount -a to /etc/fstab?

Comment: No.
The entry in /etc/fstab should look exactly the way you mentioned.
192.168.0.24:/mnt/Toshiba/dietpi_userdata /mnt/nas nfs defaults 0 0
Eventually use the hostname instead of IP address.
The last option is to do this way like it is described here:
https://www.linuxtechi.com/automount-nfs-share-in-linux-using-autofs/

Comment: Thanks, that autofs option works.